# Repository architecture vs Client-Server architecture?

Tags: architecture, repository, client-server

Prepping for an exam and it asks:

> What are the key aspects of a repository architecture that
>   differentiate it from a client-server architecture?

My response to that is:

> Repository architecture is centralised data that can be accessed by multiple
>   components to store and edit data, a change on one component is
>   replicated across all components, data is processed on the client
>   side. Client-Server can have multiple servers and clients each
>   interacting with each other to offer services, data and services are
>   processed on the server side.

Is that correct, and would you think that answers the question? I also feel like Client-Server and Repository are not so easily comparable, as you could have a repository system operating within a Client-Server architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not agree. Repository is definitely a way to implement Client-Server pattern, in particular - server side. Having a server implies existence of a client, at least one. Even if there is no **centralized** database somewhere, there still exists **data layer** that might be local to a client. Without **somewhat kind** of data layer you're limited to "in-memory" applications only: they have no state at all (including absence of user settings, for example). I assume that your question is not limited to those.

The idea stays behind repository pattern is a necessity to abstract out data IO **implementation details**. It hides certain structure of database, it's configuration, mapping and (rarely) validation logic inside of an appropriate `IRepository` class. Normally these guys are generic, so programmers deal with `IRepository<T>` with some additional constraints put on the `T`. Hence, having such an interface in place allows you to: 1) use conceptually different databases simultaneously, keeping other code unware of their principal differences (imagine traditional SQL along with graph-based database), 2) replacing different databases with no change made to outter world: say, you decided to get rid of `MSSQL` and move to a `Neo4j` or vice versa, 3) finally, the last but definitely not the least, you get a razor-sharp edge of a certain "responsibility" - data IO. That acts as a convinient extension point to inject extensions like validation or logging.